# Calculate running total and running total details

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

In the following table I need to get the running total as well as the details of running total.

[image: running total and details of running total]

For example, in this table for personnel_id=12

> **Summary side :**
>
> - at 2018-10-19 21:23:00.567 Transaction_Type is assign and MACHINECOUNT   =1, so total machines assigned by that time is 1
> - at 2018-10-19 21:23:17.077 Transaction_Type is assign and MACHINECOUNT =1,and total machines assigned by that time is 2
> - at 2018-10-19 21:26:33.513 Transaction_Type is assign and MACHINECOUNT =1, and total machines assigned by that time is 3
> - at 2018-10-19 21:26:58.980 Transaction_Type is unassign and MACHINECOUNT =1, and total machines assigned by that time is 2  and so
>     on
>
> **on the details side :**
>
> - on the 2nd row,  machinecount was 2, so i need which batch_run_step_ids are included to get the count
> - on the 3rd row,  machinecount was 3, so i need which batch run steps are included to get the count and so on

[image: summary]

I was able to get the summary using sum function partition by personnel, but I need to get the details of machinecount. For example, in summary screenshot, second row machine assigned by time is 2 and I need the details of these two machines, i.e which steps/rows are included to get this total.

[image: expected details for first four records in summary]

Comment: You want to do and aggregate function `count` grouping the data by the columns DATE_TIME and TRANSACTION_TYPE? If so, [there are many questions answering that](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=group+by+count+%5Bsql%5D)  You mention summary side and details side, are there two different tables? Consider editing your question adding extra info, what you have tried, what is the problem you are having.

Comment: @bradbury9 - i've updated the post with more details, please can you take a look

Answer (score 0):

For the first query, you need to use `SUM()` **Window Function** for the filed `MACHINECOUNT` in your `select` statement as below:

Summary query:

```
select
    [your_columns],
    sum((case Transaction_Type when 'assign' then MACHINECOUN when 'unassign' then MACHINECOUN * -1 end))
    over(partition by personnel_id order by DATE_TIME)  as [RunningTotal]
from
    [your_table]
```

Comment: Or a regular group by, depends on what the expected results are, imho it is a bit unclear question.

Comment: @bradbury9 your are right. the solution depends on the results he needs. both of them might correct.

Comment: @MohammadMohabbati - thanks for the help :) i also need to know the details for the running total,, for example if sum is 2, then which batch_run_step_id as involved to get that sum

Comment: @DeepakGoyal if you mean the order of running total, it depends on the field you used in `order by` section that in your case I used `DATE_TIME`. You can change it to every column you need to have the running total.

Comment: @MohammadMohabbati- i just added the more details in this post, can you please take a look on the description.

Comment: @DeepakGoyal could you provide a sample result you expect?

Comment: @MohammadMohabbati- i have added another screenshot of expected results for first four record of summary table. please take a look.

Comment: for example : in summary(third) i have 3 machines assigned by time and batch run step id 166,164 and 165 are included to get the machine count

Comment: @DeepakGoyal do you need 2 query and results sets? The first one for the summary and the second for the detail?

Comment: @MohammadMohabbati -yes, that's correct, i need 2 query and results sets, The first one for the summary and the second for the detail

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want a cumulative conditional sum:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when transaction_type = 'assign' then 1
                when transaction_type = 'unassign' then -1
                else 0
           end) over (partition by personnel_id
                      order by date_time
                     ) as machine_assigned_by_time
from t;
```